# How to make a border that touches the bottom of the nav on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my menu, but I am having a small problem.
I want the red border on hover to touch the border-bottom of the nav. So it looks like this:

[image]

How can I get this effect? I have tried but my code below is doing this:

[image]

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #546478;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

.nav__container {
    max-width: 93.75rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px;
}

li:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.hero__nav-items {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.hero_nav-list {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero__container">
    <nav>
      <div class="hero__nav-logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png">    
      </div>
      <div class="hero__nav-items">
        <ul class="hero_nav-list">
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove padding and margin from `hero_nav-list` and add padding in `li`

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #546478;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.nav__container {
    max-width: 93.75rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

li:hover {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}

.hero__nav-items {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.hero_nav-list {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero__container">
    <nav>
      <div class="hero__nav-logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png">    
      </div>
      <div class="hero__nav-items">
        <ul class="hero_nav-list">
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why does it push down the border by 1px on my screen?

Comment: @Dave just adjust the padding of li to get perfect fit

Comment: @MinalChauhan Actually no, that is not what the OP is asking about. This is why code-only answers are discouraged on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `margin` instead of `padding` to create the space underneath the text. Borders apply to the outside including padding, but excluding the margin`.

See the working example at the end, and the changes you need are here:

1. Change the margin to padding for your `li`: `li { padding: 20px; /* change margin to padding */ }`
2. You also need to remove the margin from the `ul` as it is adding more space.
   `.hero_nav-list { margin: 0;}`
3. Remove the padding to the top & bottom of `nav`: `nav { padding: 0px 20px; }`
4. To make the borders overlap, make the `li` bottom margin `-1px`: `li { margin-bottom: -1px; }`
5. dd an "invisible" border that will be replaced by the red border  - this will stop the nav border jumping on hover: `li { border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; }`

**Working Example:**

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #546478;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__container {
  max-width: 93.75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

li:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.hero__nav-items {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.hero_nav-list {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero__container">
    <nav>
      <div class="hero__nav-logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
      </div>

      <div class="hero__nav-items">
        <ul class="hero_nav-list">
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `padding` rather than `margin`

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #546478;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav__container {
  max-width: 93.75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

li:hover {
  border-bottom-color: red;
  transition: all .3s
}

.hero__nav-items {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.hero_nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero__container">
    <nav>
      <div class="hero__nav-logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png">    
      </div>
      <div class="hero__nav-items">
        <ul class="hero_nav-list">
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```